# Automate Testing R Function Call

Tags: r, unit-testing, loops

How do I automate the input to test this R function?

I don't know much if anything about R, but I've been given the task of testing the output of an R function. I need to test the output against 10,000 rows of data to make sure the output is correct. This is too much to do by hand.

I've simplified the code. It takes in a number of inputs and spits out three rows of output.

```
run(calculate_fnscore, list("MonthsEmployed" = 1,
                                  "MonthlyRent" = 0,
                                  "CO_Age" = NULL,
                                  "LN_ialenofres" = NULL,
                                  "LN_addrchanges60" = NULL,
                                  "FICO_pb" = NULL,
                                  "NewVehInd" = boolean_to_bit(FALSE)))
```

There are many more inputs, these are just a few. The output looks like this:

```
$fnscore_1.0
[1] 119.6417  22.3203   0.0000   0.0000 142.0000
$fnscoreMax_1.0
[1] 119.64172  50.86302   0.00000   0.00000 171.00000
$fnscoreMin_1.0
[1] 119.641719  -7.634004   0.000000   0.000000 112.000000
```

I'm going to get an Excel file I can turn into a CSV file that has different inputs and what the score SHOULD equal. I need to loop through those inputs and scores to get outputs. If I do 10,000 inputs by hand it will take forever and I have 6 more functions I need to test.

Any help is appreciated turning this into a loop and an output I can examine to compare the scores.

Comment: Is your data in a data frame? is calculate_fnscore a function? Are you running a function on each row of your data?

Comment: Is your data in a data frame? - no, unless I can get the csv file into a dataframe. calculate_fnscore a function? Yes Are you running a function on each row of your data? Yes

Comment: OK, so what format is your data in? After you read it from the csv file?

Comment: Let me back up and start with data format so as not to cause confusion. As of right now, I don't have the data. What you see for the sample code is the format the data would be in. I will be getting the data soon in a CSV file. I would need to put those values into the function and run it. So, I would like to be able to take the data from the CSV and in some way put it into the function automatically and run the function. The data will be in the expected format for each field. I don't have any reservations about the data format.

Comment: Without specifics we can only engage in guesswork. Your function seems to accept a list as the second argument, which is, I guess, your data. But will your data also be in a list (list of lists)? Or something else? This is important.

Comment: Yes, my data will be in a list and will have the same variable names for columns that get passed into the function.

Comment: You might want to check `mapply`!